# How do I use dynamoDb for sessions in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-dynamodb

I want to use Amazon Dynamodb for storing sessions in CI using dynamoDb session handler. An example will be handful

Comment: Hello!
Have you checked https://github.com/linuxjuggler/codeigniter-amazon-sdk/blob/master/libraries/aws-sdk-for-php/services/dynamodb.class.php and main page AWS Doc for PHP SDK - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/feature-dynamodb-session-handler.html

Comment: Have you checked [examples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/CodeSamples.PHP.html) from the docs?